# Map nested JSON list to Object array in Spring Boot with Jackson

Tags: java, spring, jackson, objectmapper

[This is the form of my response JSON.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOWhD.png)

The top-level is a List, but the Objects I really care about are in the "Results" list, [which here is an example of one of them expanded (they are maps).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EZ3r.png) Each "result" is basically a recipe and information pertaining to that recipe. I am currently doing:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Recipe[] recipes = mapper.readValue(json, Recipe[].class);
```

But it is failing on the first character:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type [Lcom.prepchef.backend.Recipe; from Object value (token JsonToken.START_OBJECT) at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 1]`

I presume because the the "results" section isn't the top-level of the JSON. But I'm not sure how to modify the readValue method to isolate the "results" section.

I would really appreciate any advice on this subject.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Json map to java object from inner - nested json property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675292/json-map-to-java-object-from-inner-nested-json-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This stackoverflow post was helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675292/json-map-to-java-object-from-inner-nested-json-property) Using JsonNode's at() method, I was able to specify "results" as though it was the top level:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(spoonacularResponse.body());
String sourceString = jsonNode.at("/results").toString();
Recipe[] recipes = mapper.readValue(sourceString, Recipe[].class);
```

Comment: Note that this parses the string into a tree, then converts it to a string, then parses it again. If result parsing is a significant fraction of overall load, this is a needlessly inefficient solution (compared to e.g. declaring a List<Results> and returning its sole entry).

Comment: Could you show the programmatic implementation of what you are describing?

Comment: I'd have to spend two hours making an example and testing it, so: no. But if you are having trouble understanding what I meant, feel free to ask questions about the specific points you find ununderstandable.

Comment: Well, "declaring a List<Results> and returning its sole entry" seems like a simple idea, just not sure how one would actually do so (nor why it would take 2 hours to go from the above 4 lines to that)

Comment: It's not writing the code, it's making sure it's tested.

Comment: BTW if it's simple, you can do it by yourself ;-)

Comment: Just asking for what methods you'd use.

Comment: Please unaccept your answer, then I can add a proper answer.

Comment: Also, please include a shortened form of your JSON response inside the question, instead of using a link. Links tend to go away.